# Why this pattern concatenates instead of returning pure array?

Tags: haskell

I am a very beginner in haskell and now I found a behaviour which I don't understand very well.
There is a excercise in a book I am reading to write a function which removes the very first match of given char and let the rest of array unmodified.
After few attempts I come up with the code which works but I dont know why. The code is as follows:

```
removeFirst r [s] 
| s == r = []
| otherwise = [s]
removeFirst r (x:xs)
| r /= x = x : removeFirst r xs
| otherwise = xs
```

Could please anyone explain to me why this call

```
removeFirst 'a' "strange"
```

works instead of returning xs, thus "nge"? Why the concatenation happens and how should the code look like to get "nge"?

Comment: Have a closer look at `| r /= x = x : removeFirst r xs`.

Comment: Zeta: thank you, now I see it. There is a lot of pain when going from fully imperative world to this weird recursion one which I start to like.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's consider only the recursive case:

```
removeFirst r (x:xs)
| r /= x = x : removeFirst r xs
| otherwise = xs
```

The sequence of calls is:

1. `removeFirst 'a' "strange"`: 
   Since `'a' /= 's'`, this evaluates to `'s' : removeFirst 'a' "trange"`
2. `removeFirst 'a' "trange"`:
   Since `'a' /= 't'`, this evaluates to `'t' : removeFirst 'a' "range"`

   But we already have `'s':` from our previous call, so altogether we get

   `'s': ('t' : removeFirst 'a' "range")`
3. `removeFirst 'a' "range"`:
   Since `'a' /= 'r'`, this evaluates to `'r' : removeFirst 'a' "ange"`.

   But we already have `'s':'t':` from our previous calls, so altogether we get

   `'s' : ('t' : ('r' : removeFirst 'a' "ange")`
4. `removeFirst 'a' "ange"`:
   Since `'a' /= 's'` is `false`, this evaluates to `xs`, which in this case is `"nge"`.

   But we already have `'s':'t':'r':` from our previous calls, so altogether we get `'s':'t':'r':"nge"`.

**UPDATE**

@Zeta provided a nice summary of the evaluated terms at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/1RXTRqPR), which I'm shamelessly including here:

```
removeFirst 'a' "strange"
= 's' : removeFirst 'a' "trange"
= 's' : 't' : removeFirst 'a' "range"
= 's' : 't' : 'r' : removeFirst 'a' "ange"
= 's' : 't' : 'r' : "nge"
= "strnge"
```

Comment: Frank, thank you. I am very sorry my reputation here is too low to allow me upvote for this exhausting answer.

Comment: @MirekSurma You're welcome, and don't worry - if you visit the site on a regular basis and answer a question from time to time, reputation will come.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: Maybe that's just my opinion, but you could improve your answer heavily by showing the [evaluated terms](http://pastebin.com/1RXTRqPR) instead of the "sequence of calls", since your lines do not really line up. Also, I always get a little bit nervous if I see `return` as "return a value" instead of `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`. (Feel free to use the paste if you want to)

Comment: @Zeta You're right, using `return` is mis-leading here. I'll include the evaluated terms from your paste in my answer.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt: didn't take that long :) Here you are.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer about your question (you already got good replies for it), but a remark about the style of your function: too imperative, not functional/type-driven enough.

When you write a function that deals with lists (or any recursive type), always start with the *base case* (empty list, node, ...) then consider the *inductive*(recursive) *case(s)* (here, something cons-ed with a list that can be the empty list, but we don't need to care as already examined in the base case).

That in mind, when we look at your code, we first notice that your pattern matching is not exhaustive, as you forgot the base case, the empty list case:

```
removeFirst _ [] = []
-- removing the first matching element of an empty list is just
-- returning that empty list
```

and your 2 pattern matchings are just the same, the first one being the second written upside down and specialized for a one item long list; rewritten to compare both:

```
removeFirst r (x:[])  -- removeFirst r (x:xs)
 | x /= r    = x : [] --  | x /= r    = x : removeFirst r xs
 | otherwise = []     --  | otherwise = xs
```

at the end, you could have written:

```
removeFirst _ [] = [] -- "_" as we don't care about the character to remove
removeFirst r (x:xs)
 | x == r    = xs
 | otherwise = x : removeFirst r xs
```

(just a matter of taste: I prefer grouping the non recursive cases at the begining and the recursive one to the end.)

Comment: nothing wrong though in starting with the inductive case, and finishing with the base case, unless they overlap (aren't mutually exclusive) of course. :)